# Does /* */ mean anything in python?

Tags: python, syntax

Coming from C++, `//` is used from single line comments, and `/* */` is used for multi line comments.

I know `//` in Python is  used for floor division, but I'm curious if `/* */` is used for anything in Python?

I'm also curious if there is any way to add multi line comments in Python?

Comment: You can try `/*` yourself, it's a syntax error!

Answer (score 1):

> I'm curious if `/* */` is used for anything in Python?

Well you can put it into a file and sure enough:

```
    /* */
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It doesn't parse.

> I'm also curious if there is any way to add multi line comments in Python?

Use triple quotes to start and close comments: